# php parsing array with multiple attributes using a $_POST method

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm trying to parse a single row of an array through a `$_POST` method, however that single row has multiple attributes. Please refer to the code below:

```
<?php
    $propertiesSQL = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM property_name WHERE cat_id = $mainid");
?>
<table>
    <form action="newadvert.php" method="post">
        <?php
            while ($propertynames = mysql_fetch_array($propertiesSQL)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=($propertynames[1])?></td>
                    <td><input name="<?=($propertynames[1])?>" type="text" id=""></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

What I'm trying to do is retrieving that array `$propertynames[1]` in the newadvert.php file with a `$_POST` method, and assign all of its attributes to different strings so I can easily use them all seperately later. It could be that I'm using a completely wrong method for using this, so I'm all ears for a different method of doing this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: <input name="<?=($propertynames[1])?>[]" type="text" id=""></td>   Note the brackets []

Comment: So what's this do, exactly?

Comment: so I did this, however I still haven't got one single clue how to apply this in retrieving the stuff with a $_POST method. :/

Answer (score 0):

Add an incrementer var like this

```
<?php
            $i=0; //An incrementer variable
            while ($propertynames = mysql_fetch_array($propertiesSQL)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Access it as $properynames[$i] instead of #propertynames[1] -->
                    <td><?=($propertynames[$i])?></td> 
                    <td><input name="<?=($propertynames[$i])?>" type="text" id=""></td>

                </tr>
                <?php
            $i++;//Increment here
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: $i is here used in the propertynames array, which gets it data from that mysql_fetch_array($propertiesSQL). So what it does is first take the 1st array, then the 2nd array etc. What I need is for it to only take the first array, but seperate all of its attributes. Also I might've explained things in this comment completely incorrect, sorry for that in advance. :X

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($propertynames[1]);`

Comment: Hmmm, odd. It shows as "NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL", even though in the output of that table they show up fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $propertiesSQL = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM property_name WHERE cat_id = $mainid");
?>
<table>
    <form action="newadvert.php" method="post">
        <?php
            while ($propertynames = mysql_fetch_array($propertiesSQL)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=($propertynames['name'])?></td>
                    <td><input name="<?=($propertynames['name'])?>" type="text" id=""></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>

Use associative array here.
```

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found a solution to the problem.

```
<?php
    $propertySQL = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM property_id WHERE cat_id = $mainid");
?>
<table>
    <form action="newadvert.php" method="post">
        <?php
            while ($propertynames = mysql_fetch_array($propertySQL)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=($propertynames['id'])?></td>
                    <td><input name="name<?=($propertynames['id'])?>" type="text" id=""></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Notice the change to the textbox: `input name="name<?=($propertynames['id'])?>"`

Then, in the file newadvert.php I once again do the propertySQL, and create a while loop to match everything:

```
$propertySQL = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM property_name WHERE cat_id = $mainid");
while ($propertyids = mysql_fetch_array($propertySQL)){
    $propid = $propertyids[0];
    echo 'name' . $propid . '<br />';
    $input = $_POST['name'.$propid];
    echo $input . "<br />";
}
```

I never before knew you can add variables when retrieving the `$_POST` before <.<

Anyhow, thanks for the help, it's because of you guys I got the idea of doing it like this :)